# QObject::deleteLater is not called as expected in my Qt Test

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I am testing a shared lib that contains a call to `deleteLater` internally.
There is no event loop running inside the library so a requirement for the application is to have a event loop running, so that all memory is properly released.

But in the test, the object dtor is not called as expected.

For example :

```
void test1() 
{
    Foo foo;
    QSignalSpy spy(&foo, SIGNAL(mySignal(Status)));

    foo.do(); // should trigger mySignal 

    QVERIFY(spy.wait(10000)); // event loop started for 10 s max
    QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1);
    QList<QVariant> sig = spy.takeFirst();
    Foo::Status status = qvariant_cast<Foo::Status>(sig.at(0));

    QVERIFY2(status == Foo:Ok, "Failed");
}
```

The class `Foo` looks like this :

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

// ... methods, signals, slots..

private slots:
 // this call is asynchronous (depends on a network reply)
 void myslot() {
     //..
     m_obj->deleteLater();
     emit mySignal(Foo:Ok);
  }
};
```

I have added some debug print in the dtor of m_obj and it is not called when the test1 is executed.

However, if i execute the test twice (by adding a test2 slot that is copy of test1), then it is called once.

My understanding is that when the signal is emitted it stops the spy event loop and then `deleteLater` is never called. 
And after that the second event loop starts  in test2, it process the pending deletion from the previous test1.

Is it correct ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Since the `QSignalSpy` and `Foo` live in the same thread, the signal `mySignal` is not delivered through the event loop but via a direct connection. Therefore, the event loop stops immediately after the signal is emitted in `myslot`. However, since `myslot` was called by the same event loop, control only returns to it when `myslot` returns. So by the time the event loop could potentially perform the cleanup requested by `deleteLater` it has already been stopped.

If you want to test that `m_obj` is cleaned up correctly you could instead create an additional `QSignalSpy` and connect it to the `QObject::destroyed` signal that every `QObject` emits when it gets destroyed.

You would, however, need to pass in `m_obj` as a dependency to `Foo` either in the constructor or through a setter instead of constructing it in `Foo` itself.

The test could then look something like this:

```
void test1()
{
    auto obj = new Obj{}; // will be assigned to `Foo::m_obj`
    Foo foo{obj};

    QSignalSpy deletion_spy(obj, &QObject::destroyed);
    QSignalSpy mysignal_spy(&Foo, &Foo::mySignal);

    QVERIFY(deletion_spy.wait(10000));
    QCOMPARE(deletion_spy.count(), 1); // verify that `obj` got deleted

    QCOMPARE(mysignal_spy.count(), 1);
    QList<QVariant> sig = spy.takeFirst();
    Foo::Status status = qvariant_cast<Foo::Status>(sig.at(0));

    QVERIFY2(status == Foo:Ok, "Failed");
}
```